# LINQ get parent with most children

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a list of `Parent` objects that has a list of `Children` objects. I need to write a query that would give me the parent that has the most children. The ORM is entity framework, so it should work with that.

Code to start with:

```
parents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Children.Max());
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should look more like this:

```
parents.OrderByDescending(p => p.Children.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your query is not correct, because `c.Children.Max()` will try to iterate over children of one parent, and if they support comparison (e.g. children are Ints), will simply return biggest of them. And most probably your Children objects are not bool, so you won't be able to even compile the code, because FirstOrDefault takes

```
Expression<T, bool>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sorting for this:

```
int maxChildCount = parents.Max(x => x.Children.Count());
var maxParent = parents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Children.Count() == maxChildCount);
```

Or as query expression:

```
var maxParent = (from p in parents
                 let max = parents.Max(x => x.Children.Count())
                 where p.Children.Count() == max).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Isn't this going to visit each record twice? Could that take longer than the order by?

Comment: Yes - it will have to traverse twice so it's `O(2n)` = `O(n)` where as sorting is `O(n lg n)`. Given that this is done over the EF query provider though most likely the sorting  + select top(1) is optimized internally to actually perform better than it should.

Comment: @BrokenGlass so Validmir's answer is more efficient both in memory and when converted to a stored expression?

Comment: @Lolcoder: Not in memory no, my approach would be more efficient already if there are more than 4 elements in the list. On a stored expression it depends how EF/SQL optimize the query plan - I just don't now.